# Error 403 when trying to access iis 6.0 web service

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, wcf, iis

This is a basic ASP.NET web service. I am try to access the service over HTTPS using an AJAX call. I can access the service from a browser over HTTPS by htting it directly, but when trying to access the service using JavaScript I get the following error (from Chrome):

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
https://mobile.kilpatricktownsend.com/hh/PSWebService.asmx/GetPeople

Looking at the iis logs show the error to be more specifically 403.1 execute access denied. The site that the web service is running under is configured as an application with Script Execute rights enabled.

The same exact code works when the Service is hosted on IIS 7.0. Both IIS 6.0 (where it is not working) and IIS 7.0  (where it is working) are using .NET 4.0

CORS is enabled in iis 7.0 and I have enabled CORS on iis 6.0 by adding the following header values to the site:

name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"
name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"

There is no proxy server between the client and the server. Everything else is standard in terms of the web site setup and the network in general.

Here is the AJAX Call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://mobile.kilpatricktownsend.com/hh/PSWebService.asmx/GetPeople",
    data: "{searchString:'" + txtBoxId.toString() + "'}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: getPeopleSucceed,
    dataType: "json",
    failure: getPeopleFailed
});
```

Comment: unable to access https://mobile.kilpatricktownsend.com/hh/PSWebService.asmx/GetPeople, is your service working?

Answer (score 0):

`I can access the service from a browser over HTTPS by htting it directly`

Only `HttpGet` requests are accessible to browsers and `HttpPost` methods are not accessible through browser & give `HTTP 405 : Method not allowed.` error.

In js ajax call, it's post `type: "POST"`, so make sure  `web service` method is decorated with `[WebMethod]` or with `[HttpPost]` in case of ASP.net method.

Also try using `JSON.stringify` in data to serialize input data like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://mobile.kilpatricktownsend.com/hh/PSWebService.asmx/GetPeople",
    data: JSON.stringify("{searchString:'" + txtBoxId.toString() + "'}"),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: getPeopleSucceed,
    dataType: "json",
    failure: getPeopleFailed
});
```